# how to use git GUI with diff-highlight?

Tags: git, git-gui

I have set up my `~/.gitconfig` as per https://www.viget.com/articles/dress-up-your-git-diffs-with-word-level-highlights.
It works well with `git diff` in terminal.

Is there a way to see the changes in [git gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) like `diff-highlight`? I mean highlight the changed words with background color.

Comment: I don’t have an answer for git gui, but have found it to be a  a little dated. The Mac version of sourcetreeapp fills in very nicely.

Comment: This [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/933872/using-diff-highlight-with-git-gui) looks helpful